# Mimicing an Apple Airplay receiver

Tags: ios11, airplay, fairplay

I've read a bunch of stuff about Airplay but since the protocol is a moveable feast it's hard to tell what bits fit where with ios11 devices.

I specifically want to run an airplay receiver within a Unity app in order to allow VR gamers to also airplay their own content to an HUD (Basically shooting stuff while also watching Netflix!)

Having got the mDNS/Zeroconf bit broadcasting that the airplay receiver is available on the device on a particular port I have a little node express server waiting on that port for http requests. I was under the impression I'd see a /setup or /fp-setup request from the device before having to do some keyserver negotiation stuff but at the moment I see no incoming requests when I select the airplay receiver on my remote ios device. Is there some pre-requisite here for both airplay and rtsp and even ntp servers to exist before the http requests begin?

Assuming I navigate beyond that issue I wonder if anyone could shed some light on using the airtunesd binary with the unicorn arm emulator within a unity app... It sounds like running the native binary is the only way these days of getting airplay to work, but how does one go about figuring out the native methods to call within what is essentially a black box? I'm new to compiled binary reverse engineering so go easy on me!